# ActionColumn's button with custom URL

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii2

I need to add new, custom button to Yii2's [ActionColumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn.html). Using examples available in the Internet, I managed to create a closure for rendering custom button and it now renders with default URL.

But, I need it with a custom URL.

I managed to get this done, by overriding `$url` value, that my custom button's closure function is fed, with URL generated using other function parameters, like that:

```
'buttons' => [
    'see' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
        $options = [
            'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'See in frontend'),
            'aria-label' => Yii::t('yii', 'See'),
            'data-pjax' => '0',
        ];
        $url = \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute(['lab/index', 'lab' => $key]);

        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>', $url, $options);
    }
],
```

It works, but it isn't too professional. I wanted to use [`urlCreator`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn.html#$urlCreator-detail) property, as shown in [Kartik's example from Yii Forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/49595-how-to-change-buttons-in-actioncolumn/page__view__findpost__p__235651):

```
'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
    if ($action === 'see') {
        return \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute(['lab/index', 'lab' => $key]);
    }
}
```

But, this example is not working. It only generates correct URL for my custom button and leaves default buttons not working, without any URL. This is understandable, assuming, how `urlCreator` works. But, how to fix this problem? How can I get access to `ActionColumn` to use `controller` property for generating URLs for default buttons or how to force it to generate these URLs for me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use like that:

```
'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
                        if ($action === 'yandexCampaign') {
                            return Url::toRoute(['add-yandex-campaign', 'id' => $model->id]);
                        } else {
                            return Url::toRoute([$action, 'id' => $model->id]);
                        }
                    }
```

You need set `else` case for default buttons.

Comment: Sounds great. But, there's still a question, why we need to play with `urlCreator` at all, to achieve this, instead of modifying `$url` directly in button's closure, as I shown in my "lazy" approach. Seems to be better to have custom button render and custom URL in one place, right?

Comment: I agree that is not best way to set code for defaults buttons. But you override method `ActionColumn::createUrl`. It means you must set code for custom and defaults buttons. Other way not set.